# Firebase scroll to load more data in ionic2

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new in firebase. How to scroll load more data in ionic2 with firebase database. I have tried so many example but didn’t find any solution.

I have used   `this._post.orderByKey().endAt(0).limitToLast(5).on('child_added',(data) =>{ })` 
but didn’t work it. Kindly help me….
see following image. i have required data on this follow.
thank

[image]

Comment: have you get any solution i have same problem